# Image statistics in PHP: average column values

Tags: php, image-processing, imagick

I want to calculate the average pixel values in each column of an image. I am considering using ImagickPixelIterator Imagick::getPixelIterator but, if I understand it correctly, it iterates row by row.

Do you think it is a good way to face the problem? Do you know a better way?

Comment: With some basic math you can go row by row and still calculate column avarage.

Comment: @Marek I know. What I don't know is if this is the most efficient way or I am missing something.

Comment: Efficiency depends on the efficiency of the library, less on your code. You have to measure it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use the image library of your choosing to resize the image to be 1 pixel high, after that you just read the pixels to have average column colors. Good luck!

Answer (score 0):

This is my alternative using Imagick::getPixelIterator :

```
        $v_row = array();
        $v_column = array();     
        $pxit = $img->getPixelIterator(); 
        foreach($pxit as $row => $pixels) { 
            foreach ($pixels as $column => $pixel) {  
                $color = $pixel->getColorValue(Imagick::COLOR_RED);
                $v_row[$row] += $color;
                $v_column[$column] += $color;
            };
        };
        foreach($v_row as &$v){ $v /= count($v_column); }
        foreach($v_column as &$v){ $v /= count($v_row); }
```

It calculates averages for columns and rows.